# how to bring X axis to Y axis 0 level in a vb.net line chart where graph goes to both + and - sidea of Y axis

Tags: vb.net

The graph I have now is shown in the left side and I want it to look like the one in the right side of the attached image

[image]

Comment: It's wpf or asp.net or something else .... put some demo code

Comment: chrtControl1.Series.Clear()
Dim s As New Series
s.Name = "Graph"
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
s.Points.AddXY(0, -1) 
s.Points.AddXY(1, 0) 
s.Points.AddXY(2,1)  
chrtControl1.Series.Add(s)

Comment: Are you looking for the [Axis.Crossing Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.axis.crossing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?